# Why mongodump shows this "skipping collection" message when doing a database dump?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

While performing a simple [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-mongodump), I encountered  this error/warning/info message

```
Tue May  8 04:22:30    skipping collection: myDb.myCollection.$myCollection.myProp_1
Tue May  8 04:22:30    skipping collection: myDb.myCollection2.$myCollection2._id_1
```

I was wondering what it means? and whether I should worry that my dump is not 100% a copy of the source?

The command line used was:

```
./mongodump -v -h localhost
```

Comment: Are these indexes?  Mongodump doesn't include indexes.